# Best Windows 10 Folder Mirroring Program or App?

Tags: windows-10, backup, file-synchronization

Hello and not sure if this is exacly the right place to ask but i am basically looking for a good pogram to mirror some folders on my pc.

I would like it so when i add/modify/delete a file or something on one disc the action is repeated for the folder on another disc, for example i have my photo album backed up in my onedrive folder on a hdd and would like anything i do to be replicated in the backup folder on an external drive (thats always plugged in of course)

I have seen some older threads asking similar things but the programs are either out dated or dont exacly fit what im after. If there is a way windows does it with programs or commands etc im all ears (and fingers) ready to try some things.

Many thanks everyone

Comment: Be aware that mirroring is a poor way of doing backups. For example, if a virus deletes (or encrypts) your files, the mirror will also delete/encrypt your backup.

Comment: I would second @Alejandro comment regarding this not being a secure backup method. Apart from my answer, you can also look into 'bash for windows 10' as an option to use *nix type commands for backups.

Comment: Yeh i understand and it does not have to be just a mirror type backup but just something to help me copy over just whats changed and not the whole entire folder all the time and also so the backups/changes are backed up more frequently. Ill take a look at the things you mentioned, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In recent years I've used **[FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org/)** (instead of SyncToy, which is not actively developed any longer), and I thoroughly recommend it. Some of it's features:

- Synchronize folders on network shares and local drives
- Synchronize mobile devices via MTP (Android, iPhone, tablet, digital camera)
- Synchronize cloud storage via SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol)
- Free FTP client: synchronize via FTP (File Transfer Protocol) and FTPS (SSL/TLS)
- Detect moved and renamed files and folders
- Manage versions and keep a history of deleted/updated files
- Compare and synchronize multiple files in parallel
- Show drive space usage for a directory tree
- Copy locked files (Volume Shadow Copy Service)
- Detect conflicts and propagate deletions
- Compare files by content
- Configure handling of Symbolic Links
- Automate sync as a batch job
- Comprehensive and detailed error reporting
- Copy NTFS extended attributes (compressed, encrypted, sparse)
- Copy NTFS security permissions
- Copy NTFS Alternate Data Streams
- Copy HFS+ extended attributes and ACLs
- Support long file paths with more than 260 characters
- Fail-safe file copy prevents data corruption
- Expand environment variables like %UserProfile%
- Use macros %time%, %date%, et al. for recurring backups
- Access variable drive letters by volume name (USB sticks)
- Prevent disc space bottlenecks via optimal sync sequence
- Highly optimized run time performance
- Include and exclude files via filter
- Handle daylight saving time changes on FAT/FAT32
- Case-sensitive synchronization
- Serialize multiple users accessing the same (network) folder via folder locking

Comment: I used it too, then moved to Bvckup2. I am too lazy to copy/paste from the [seven answers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3397+bvckup2) that I already gave extoling this fine software (shadow copy (copying open files) alone is worth the minimal purchase price). Give it a look

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using [Robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)'s flag to perform copy-jobs at intervals, you could use two tools I've had success with.

**SyncToy**

> SyncToy 2.1 is a free application that synchronizes files and folders
>   between locations. Typical uses include sharing files, such as photos,
>   with other computers and creating backup copies of files and folders.

[Downloadable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155) here, or you can look for [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/synctoy/) solutions here.

This was developed, and then abandoned by Microsoft - therefore, use at your own risk.

**DSyncronize**

I have used (and still do) implement this tool. [DSyncronize](http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/) has many powerful options for "mirroring" and backing up UNC paths to other locations.

**Related Questions**

Note: I am involved with all these questions.

1. [CLI Backup Tool](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/36577/9311)
2. [Data Recovery and Backup](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/24908/free-aud-backup-solution)
3. [Automatic Backups](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/49063/9311)
4. [HDD Backup](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/48340/9311)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help i will definatly look into that program because im simply fed up of manually copying over all the files everytime i want to backup when its just a few files that may have been changed, added or deleted so just need something that could help me with that, thanks